# react-select first item always focused after setting menu open to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, react-select

I have a functional component, ResultsSelect, that returns a Select component from react-select package. Each option has a checkbox and a label. When I click on

- the checkbox I don't want to close the menu
- the label I want to close the menu

Options data are passed to the Select as props. One option is like that:

```
{ value: string, label: string, checked: boolean }
```

The problem is that every time I click on a checkbox, the first item in the list becomes focused for a micro second (maybe because of *setMenuIsOpen(true)* in *handleOptionClick* ?). Here is my functional component:

```
const ResultsSelect = ({ selectedId, onOptionClick, onCheckboxClick, options }) => {    
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState();

  const handleCheckboxClick = (id, checked) => {
    onCheckboxClick(id, checked);
    setMenuIsOpen(true);
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (id) => {
    onOptionClick(id);
    setMenuIsOpen(undefined);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (_, { action, prevInputValue }) => {
    if (action === 'menu-close' && !prevInputValue) {
      setMenuIsOpen(undefined);
    }
    return prevInputValue;
  };

  const selectedOption = useMemo(() => {
    return options.find((option) => option.value === selectedId);
  }, [selectedId]);

  const customStyles = useMemo(
    () => ({
      option: (defaultStyles, state) => {
        return {
          ...defaultStyles,
          backgroundColor: state.isFocused
            ? 'red'
            : state.isSelected
            ? 'green'
            : 'blue',
          color: 'black'
        };
      }
    }),
    []
  );

  const Option = ({ ...props }) => {
    const content = useMemo(() => {
      return (
        <components.Option {...props}>
          <div>
            <Form.Check 
              type='checkbox' 
              onChange={(evt) => onCheckboxClick(props.data.value, evt.target.checked)}
              checked={props.data.checked}
            />
            <div onClick={() => handleOptionClick(props.data.value)}>
              {props.data.label}
            </div>
          </div>
        </components.Option>
      );
    }, [
      props.data.value,
      props.data.label,
      props.data.checked,
      props.isSelected,
      props.isFocused
    ]);
    return content;
  };

  const SingleValue = ({ ...props }) => {
    const content = useMemo(() => {
      return (
        <components.SingleValue {...props}>
          <span title={props.data.label}>{props.data.label}</span>
        </components.SingleValue>
      );
    }, [props.data.label]);
    return content;
  };

  return (
    <Select
      value={selectedOption}
      options={options}
      components={{ SingleValue, Option }}
      styles={customStyles}
      menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
    />
  );
};

export default ResultsSelect;
```

Any idea to avoid that 'glitch'?